# Why my node server processes the request twice?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have following simple node server.

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, resp) {

    console.log("request arrived.")
    resp.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    resp.end("Hello world!!");

}).listen(3000);
```

Whenever I hit the request using url  `http://localhost:3000/`,
it printing   `request arrived` message two times.

I don't know,what is the exact reason for it.
Will some please explain it.

I have attached screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is most likely that the browser is requesting for the `favicon.ico` file. You can confirm that by printing the URL, like this

```
console.log("request arrived for URL", req.url);
```

When I tried this on my machine, with Chrome browser, I got

```
request arrived for URL /
request arrived for URL /favicon.ico
```

---

If you want to avoid that, then you need to handle the `favicon` request specially. Probably, you can do something like this, as shown [here](https://gist.github.com/kentbrew/763822)

```
if (req.url === '/favicon.ico') {
    resp.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon'} );
    resp.end();
    console.log('favicon requested');
    return;
}

console.log("request arrived.")
resp.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
resp.end("Hello world!!");
```

Comment: Thanks. you are right.I have checked.But how we can avoid it?Because it is processing the request two time

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the follow-up question "I have checked.But how we can avoid it?" answer is put the lines in previous answer just below the line that has http.createServer, so that you end up with something like following which contains 4 lines added to the original code in question:

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, resp) {
    if (req.url === '/favicon.ico') {
      res.end();
      return;
    }

    console.log("request arrived.")
    resp.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    resp.end("Hello world!!");

}).listen(3000);
```